# Not sending/ receiving data properly java

Tags: java

Currently I am trying to create an array of objects and pass in its name through string that I split. But for some reason its not sending the data correctly.

```
data = reader.readLine().split("(?<=\\d)\\s+|\\s+at\\s+");
        Products[i] = new Product();
        Products[i].setName(data[1]);
```

This is the get and set methods for the other class.

```
public void setName(String productName){

    productName = this.name;

}
public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}
```

All name is, is a private string. 
Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: clarify the question properly. Code should be given in a little bit more detail.

Comment: Did you try putting dbug messages to see what your split returns you? That would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

Update your `setName` method -

```
public void setName(String productName){
    this.name = productName;
}
```